# What can a process with UID 0 do that a process with EUID 0 can't?

Tags: macos, root, userid, uid, setuid

I realised I've missed a subtlety with user IDs (UID) and effective user IDs (EUID) and need some clarification. N.B. I'm working on macOS, although I suspect everything makes sense in a Linux world as well.

I've created a binary and set the setuid bit on it (with `chmod +s`). If I run this binary and log the values from `getuid()` and `geteuid()` then I see UID=501 (my regular user) and EUID=0 (root). I can futher call `setuid(0)` to set UID=0.

My question is, when would I need to do that? i.e. What can my process do with (UID, EUID)=(0,0) that it can't do with (UID, EUID)=(501,0)?

Comment: The former can run off filesystems mounted with `nosuid`...

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you run a binary, it runs as you.  ie: your UID.
When you setuid, the binary no longer runs as you, but as the owner of the file.
In this case that user is root.

root (uid=0) can do just about anything, including changing their own UID.
There shouldn't be any difference between (0,0) (501,0) except.....
One is YOU running something as root and the other is root running something as root.
Essentially, it makes you root.

Comment: Sure, I understand that conceptually. But I'm not clear what, if any, functional difference that makes. I can, for example, see in *ps* output that there's a binary running as root on behalf of me, but that's really just informational.

Comment: One clue I've found is in the sudo source code: `/* Become full root (not just setuid) so user cannot kill us. */ if (setuid(ROOT_UID) == -1)`. This one is sort of obvious now I see it. But I'm trying to understand what other impacts there are.

Comment: programs like firehol will read the uid and take different actions depending on whether or not it is root the one requesting the action and for that they reak the uid.